# Is there a way to fill subreports as we do with main reports? ( JasperReports )

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans, subreport, names

Is there a way to fill subreports, as we do with main reports, and then add them to the main report?

Something like:

```
fillReportxxx(subreport, subParams, subDataSource);
mainParams.put("subreport", subreport);
fillReportxxx(mainReport, mainParams, mainDataSource);
```

All the ways that I have seen on Internet speak about pass all dataSources and parameters from the main report to the subreports. But it would be really helpful in my case to do it in that way.

**Why?**

I have my main bean and my subreport bean created and ready to be used as dataSource, but they have some field names in common, so I guess that I can't pass all of them to the main report without conflict (I have a lot of them: names and subreports). And I suppose that if I centralize all data input into my main report I would have to create an unified bean class, right?
I have some parameters name in conflict (same name in main and in subs) as well but it is a minor issue (is it an issue?).

I am starting with JasperReports and I find that filling each report separately would be the more intuitive way. Also, in the docu says:

> Since subreports are normal reports themselves, they are compiled and filled just like
>   other reports. This means that they also require a data source from which to get the data
>   when they are filled. They can also rely on parameters for additional information to use
>   when being filled.
>   There are two ways to supply parameter values to a subreport.
>   You can supply a map containing the parameter values, as when filling a normal report
>   with data, using one of the fillReportXXX() methods exposed by the
>   JasperFillManager class (see “Filling Report Templates” on page 19)

**Little fix**

I have seen some code where the subreport beans are passed as parameter, and it works:

```
JRDataSource dataSourceSubReport = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listOfBeans);
parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", subReport);
parameters.put("criteriosDS", dataSourceSubReport);

//and then fill the main normally
fillReportxxx(mainReport, parameters, mainDataSource);
```

This fix my major problem with the dataSource conflicts, but I find it, maybe, a bit dirty. 
I guess that have to be a cleaner way.

**Another way?**

Maybe I have missed a way to pass my different beans and parameters from the main report to the subreport mantaining the names and the beans without conflicts.

Comment: You can call a getter method from 'Date Source Expression' property present in iReport.


"new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(new com.reportDataSource.ReportDataSource().getSubReportDataSource())"

Comment: @efex09 Sorry I don't understand... for what would be that expresion?